# Ambari doesnt start after postgresql Upgrade

Tags: postgresql, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

We have a four-node Hadoop cluster with HDP 2.4 and Kerberos installed in it. As this is our production cluster, We wanted to have HA for all the services including the PostgreSQL database which is used by Hive, Ambari, and Oozie for storing the metadata. However, the version of our postgreSQL, which is 8.4.2 doesn't support the inbuilt feature(stream replication) of Postgres.

So, we have decided to upgrade PostgreSQL to a version(9.3) ambari supports.

I followed [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98144/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-8-4-to-9-4) link to upgrade the Postgres. Everything went well. Expect that, we are getting the following error when restarting ambari server.

```
Ambari Server running with administrator privileges.
Running initdb: This may take upto a minute.
Data directory is not empty!
[FAILED]
```

Could someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for the issue [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/102174/ambari-doesnt-start-after-postgresql-upgrade.html#answer-102188).

Answer (score 2):

Your server want's to initilize the Database. I guess your Server does not see the Ambari DB. Use `ambari-server setup` zu restore the database Connection. Than the sever should start perfectly.